# Show another page than Home Page after starting manual workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow

After manually starting workflow my browser always goes automatically to Home Page of my site. Can I change it? I want to inform users that after running this workflow they need to wait few minutes before taking next actions, because workflow have to finish. Firstly I was thinking about message box in which this information will be written but it could be too hard for me especially that I don't have access to Visual Studio. So I think that a simple another page which contains only text will be better option.

I am using SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this in the past using javascript. Both approaches are the same, but I prefer to start workflows using javascript through SOAP web services or CSOM. Many ways to add this to pages. I actually added it through a callout on the edit control block. Then I could actually tell the user what I wanted and also control the page they went to next if needed. This process could be extended further depending on your needs. An older example I found:

```
function AddCustomAction(renderCtx, calloutActionMenu) {
    calloutActionMenu.addAction(new CalloutAction({
        text: "PCR Approval",
        tooltip: 'Start the PCR Approval Workflow',
        onClickCallback: function () {
            console.log('Callback from custom action');
            var workflowParams = "<Data><Approvers></Approvers><NotificationMessage></NotificationMessage><DurationforSerialTasks></DurationforSerialTasks><DurationUnits></DurationUnits><CC></CC><CancelonRejection></CancelonRejection><CancelonChange></CancelonChange><EnableContentApproval></EnableContentApproval></Data>";
            waitDialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose('Starting PCR Approval Workflow.', 'Please, wait...', 250, 700);
            $().SPServices({
                operation: "GetTemplatesForItem",
                item: "https://" + window.location.host + renderCtx.CurrentItem.FileRef,
                async: true,
                completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                    var currentItemURL = this.item;
                    $(xData.responseXML).find("WorkflowTemplates > WorkflowTemplate").each(function (i, e) {
                        if ($(this).attr("Name") == "Approval") {
                            var guid = $(this).find("WorkflowTemplateIdSet").attr("TemplateId");
                            if (guid != null) {
                                workflowGUID = "{" + guid + "}";
                                logit("workflowGUID - " + workflowGUID);
                                $().SPServices({
                                    operation: "StartWorkflow",
                                    item: currentItemURL,
                                    templateId: workflowGUID,
                                    workflowParameters: workflowParams,
                                    async: true,
                                    completefunc: function () {
                                        if (waitDialog != null) {  waitDialog.close(); }
                                        SP.UI.Notify.addNotification("Started PCR Approval Workflow.", false);
                                        window.location.reload();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }));
```

There were actually more actions but this is a good starting point. This was on a jslink rendering template for a list. I chose to use SPServices library at that time but you could try CSOM code as well.

Comment: Thanks for your solution but unfortunately it will be too hard for me. I attained my goal in other way by using Initiation Parameters in SharePoint Designer, where Yes/No Parameter is used with information about waiting few minutes. It's a little walkaround method but it is working for me.